# REGEX to parse template echo

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse some input using regex. The input will be in the format:

{somevalue:3}

The aim is to display 'som' (no quotemarks).

At the moment, I have:

```
 'echo' => array(
            'search' => '~\{((?:'.$this->preg['var'].')(?:\.)?)\}~sU',
            'replace' => "'.\$this->_get('\\1').'"
        )
```

Which works great with my template system, to echo the standard variable (i.e. 'somevalue'). However, I wish to allow the user to use the : delimiter to limit the number of characters to output (i.e. {somevalue:3} would display 'som').

I tried:

```
'echo' => array(
            'search' => '~\{((?:'.$this->preg['var'].')(?:\.)?:(.*)/)\}~sU',
            'replace' => "'.substr(\$this->_get('\\1'),0,\\2).'"
        )
```

But this didn't work. I don't really understand regex to be honest so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra '/' in the new search expression.

```
                                                       |
                                                       v
'search' => '~\{((?:'.$this->preg['var'].')(?:\.)?:(.*)/)\}~sU',
```

I'm not familiar with the templating system you're using, but it appears that the replace expression would need to be changed as well.

```
'replace' => "'.substr(\$this->_get('\\1'),0,\$this->_get('\\2')).'"
```

Put these together and you'd get something like this to try:

```
'echo' => array(
            'search' => '~\{((?:'.$this->preg['var'].')(?:\.)?:(.*))\}~sU',
            'replace' => "'.substr(\$this->_get('\\1'),0,\$this->_get('\\2')).'"
        )
```

It should be noted that if this works, the old way of doing input won't work anymore. In other words, you'll always have to use the format `{<string>:<num_of_chars>}` and not just `{<string>}`.

Comment: I see what you mean about the original {string} not working anymore. To get around this, i've changed it so that this is a new element in the array called 'echolimit', so existing tags aren't affected. I tried your code, but it didn't work. I have changed it to: `'echolimit' => array(
            'search' => '~\{((?:'.$this->preg['var'].')(?:\.)?:(.*))\}~sU',
            'replace' => "'.substr(\$this->_get('\\1'),0,'\\2').'"
   ),`  but now it doesn't display anything (other existing {tags} work perfectly still).

Comment: The substr should take the first parameter as the string, second as the offset and the third as the length. Your version had the third parameter as using $this->_get('\\2') - however the $this->_get() is a function which finds the tag variable from the template to display. In this case, all it should have is the number that was passed after the : in the {stringtodisplay:limit} tag

Comment: Since I don't know much about the template engine you're using, I assumed that `$this->_get('\\1')` meant to get the first capture group from the $this->preg() call. Since we're adding a second capture group to get the number, I assumed $this->_get('\\2') would do this. I know see that my code nested capture groups, which isn't necessary. Could you give this a try? `'echolimit' => array( 'search' => '~\{((?:'.$this->preg['var'].')(?:\.)?):([0-9]+)\}~sU', 'replace' => "'.substr(\$this->_get('\\1'),0,\$this->_get('\\2')).'" )`

Comment: I'm marking this as correct as despite it not working right off the bat, it was the right idea to help me get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = preg_replace_callback(
       '/\{([^:]+):(\d+)\}/',
       create_function('$m', 'return substr($m[1], 0, $m[2]);'), $s);
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/QJLPVS)**.

Comment: The code here won't fit with the existing template parser, which is the problem. So despite it displaying 'som' I need the code in the same form as what I provided above unfortunately. It'd be far too time consuming and redundant to rewrite the whole parsing algorithm. Do you know how to get your code into the same style as I provided?